# sparkpb UDF compile giving "error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type frameless.TypedEncoder[Array[Byte]]"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, implicit

I'm a scala newbie, using pyspark extensively (on DataBricks, FWIW). I'm finding that Protobuf deserialization is too slow for me in python, so I'm porting my deserialization udf to scala.

I've compiled my `.proto` files to scala and then a JAR using `scalapb` as described [here](https://scalapb.github.io/docs/sparksql/)

When I try to use [these](https://scalapb.github.io/docs/sparksql/#udfs) instructions to create a UDF like this:

```
import gnmi.gnmi._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, DataFrame, functions => F}
import spark.implicits.StringToColumn
import scalapb.spark.ProtoSQL

// import scalapb.spark.ProtoSQL.implicits._
import scalapb.spark.Implicits._

val deserialize_proto_udf = ProtoSQL.udf { bytes: Array[Byte] => SubscribeResponse.parseFrom(bytes) }
```

I get the following error:

```
command-4409173194576223:9: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type frameless.TypedEncoder[Array[Byte]]
val deserialize_proto_udf = ProtoSQL.udf { bytes: Array[Byte] => SubscribeResponse.parseFrom(bytes) }
```

I've double checked that I'm importing the correct implicits, to no avail. I'm pretty fuzzy on implicits, evidence parameters and scala in general.

I would really appreciate it if someone would point me in the right direction.  I don't even know how to start diagnosing!!!

#### Update

It seems like `frameless` doesn't include an implicit encoder for `Array[Byte]`???
This works:

```
frameless.TypedEncoder[Byte]
```

this does not:

```
frameless.TypedEncoder[Array[Byte]]
```

The [code](https://github.com/typelevel/frameless/blob/68a9bd547659eae2868f16e21bc299e4a1feb5f6/dataset/src/main/scala/frameless/TypedEncoder.scala#L273) for `frameless.TypedEncoder` seems to include a generic `Array` encoder, but I'm not sure I'm reading it correctly.

@Dymtro, Thanks for the suggestion.  That helped.

Does anyone have ideas about what is going on here?

#### Update

Ok, progress - this looks like a DataBricks issue.  I think that the notebook does something like the following on startup:

```
import spark.implicits._
```

I'm using `scalapb`, which [requires that you don't do that](https://scalapb.github.io/docs/sparksql#datasets-and-none-is-not-a-term)

I'm hunting for a way to disable that automatic import now, or "unimport" or "shadow" those modules after they get imported.

Comment: There are ways to debug implicits (at compile time) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348301/in-scala-2-or-3-is-it-possible-to-debug-implicit-resolution-process-in-runtime/ If you're certain what implicits to use then you can resolve implicits manually and see new compile error.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Thanks!  That is helpful. I added some more info.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Did you have a chance to check whether "unimporting" like in my answer helps?

Comment: Do you have any updates?

Comment: Thanks for helping out!  The solution below doesn't seem to work, sadly.  I'm working around it by build a map and writing that out instead, but it's a pretty inefficient process

Answer (score 2):

If `spark.implicits._` are already imported then a way to "unimport" (hide or shadow them) is to create a duplicate object and import it too

```
object implicitShadowing extends SQLImplicits with Serializable {
  protected override def _sqlContext: SQLContext = ???
}

import implicitShadowing._
```

Testing for `case class Person(id: Long, name: String)`

```scala
// no import

List(Person(1, "a")).toDS() // doesn't compile, value toDS is not a member of List[Person]
```

```scala
import spark.implicits._

List(Person(1, "a")).toDS() // compiles
```

```scala
import spark.implicits._
import implicitShadowing._

List(Person(1, "a")).toDS() // doesn't compile, value toDS is not a member of List[Person]
```

[How to override an implicit value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28780101/how-to-override-an-implicit-value)

[Wildcard Import, then Hide Particular Implicit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661654/wildcard-import-then-hide-particular-implicit)

[How to override an implicit value, that is imported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51593632/how-to-override-an-implicit-value-that-is-imported)

[How can an implicit be unimported from the Scala repl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592324/how-can-an-implicit-be-unimported-from-the-scala-repl)

[Not able to hide Scala Class from Import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133957/not-able-to-hide-scala-class-from-import)

[NullPointerException on implicit resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917884/nullpointerexception-on-implicit-resolution)

[Constructing an overridable implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36518538/constructing-an-overridable-implicit)

[Caching the circe implicitly resolved Encoder/Decoder instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411094/caching-the-circe-implicitly-resolved-encoder-decoder-instances)

[Scala implicit def do not work if the def name is toString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872032/scala-implicit-def-do-not-work-if-the-def-name-is-tostring)

[Is there a workaround for this format parameter in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73712378/is-there-a-workaround-for-this-format-parameter-in-scala)

Please check whether this helps.

Possible problem can be that you don't want just to unimport `spark.implicits._` (`scalapb.spark.Implicits._`), you probably want to import `scalapb.spark.ProtoSQL.implicits._` too. And I don't know whether `implicitShadowing._` shadow some of them too.

Another possible workaround is to resolve implicits manually and use them explicitly.